# RANSAC differentiating between line and plane

Tags: algorithm, ransac

I am trying to extract planes from a 3D point dataset containing power cables. Now the power cables are also getting extracted as planes. So my question is it possible to use RANSAC to differentiate between a line and plane. I can perform an eigen value based analysis but I am looking for some way to perform as part of the RANSAC algorithm itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out a simple solution. Posting it for others help. RANSAC starts with finding a plane from three points. So we find the two vectors from three points. We can check the dot product of two vectors to find if they are close to 1. If they are, they represent a line.